# Why is there no דגש in the ת in the word "וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

I am told that a בגדכפת letter takes a דגש following a closed syllable (examples of this: [נִשְׁ**בַּ֧**ע](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0), [בְּקִרְ**בֶּ֑**ךָ](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.15?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0) and [לְנֶגְ**דְּ**כֶם֙](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.1.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he)) (i.e. ends with the letter and not the vowel), so why do words like:

> [וּכְ**תַ**בְתָּ֛ם](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0)

> [כַּנְ**פֵ֥**י](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.38?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0)

> [מַלְ**כֵ֥**י](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.1.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he)

> [אַדְמַתְ**כֶ֗**ם](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.1.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he)

not take a דגש in the first ת?

Comment: These are often called sheva merachef. I believe the reason is that the syllable is historically not closed (w'kh'tavtem), but by the Masoretic era, the change was already underway.

Comment: As an example of "change in progress", check out לצבא in Num 4:23 vs Isaiah 31:4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct verb form without the *and* should be: כְּתַבְתָּם – *inscribe them*. Although in second person plural the *kamatz* shortens to a *sheva na,* the *tav* won't receive a *dagesh,* because it doesn't come after a closed syllable. The syllabication of the word is thus כְּתַבְ-תָּם, because the *sheva* doesn't qualify for its own syllable. The same is the case with the -וְ prefix: even though it tranforms to -וּ, it's still not a syllable, so the syllabication remains וּכְתַבְ-תָּם however strange it seems. Therefore, we don't have a closed syllable "-וּכְ" as you write, but rather a single one as written previously, and you won't have a *dagesh* in the *tav.*

See also this [French site](http://dikdouk.free.fr/DageshIV.htm) with great examples* and an explanation of the [Hebrew syllabication](http://dikdouk.free.fr/SyllabeI.htm).

Regarding your other examples, many words with two *segol* in them behave in a similar way by not having a *dagesh* after a closed syllable. Some examples are:

| singular | plural | construct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| דֶּרֶךְ | דְּרָכִים | דַּרְ**כֵ**י |
| מֶלֶךְ | מְלָכִים | מַלְ**כֵ**י |
| דֶּלֶת | דְּלָתוֹת | דַּלְ**ת**וֹת |
| כֶּלֶב | כְּלָבִים | כַּלְ**בֵ**י |
| חֶסֶד | חֲסָדִים | חַסְ**דֵ**י |
| אֶלֶף | אֲלָפִים | אַלְ**פֵ**י |
| חֶרֶב | חֲרָבוֹת | חַרְ**ב**וֹת |
| בֶּגֶד | בְּגָדִים | בִּגְ**דֵ**י |
| כָּנָף | כְּנָפַיִם | כַּנְ**פֵ**י |

Here the problem is that in plural the first vowel becomes a *sheva* or – in case of gutturals – a *chataf patach.* In the construct form the second vowel should be also shortened, but it is impossible, because there would be two consecutive *sheva* in the beginning. So the first *sheva* becomes a short vowel – either a *patach* (דרך) or a *chirik* (בגד), and the second vowel will be a *sheva* in these cases, while the *dagesh* is still omitted as in the plural base form.

Regarding nouns with ה ending, this ה hardens to a ת in the construct form (which was like a *th* sound in *think* in the olden days), but it seems that concerning the *dagesh* it was still considered an open syllable and the כ wasn't hardened (see עָרְלַתְכֶם, חָכְמַתְכֶם, גְּבוּרַתְכֶם, כְּהוּנַּתְכֶם, אֲחוּזַּתְכֶם). Although we should note that in other words like לְבַבְכֶם, אֶתְכֶם the כֶם- suffix doesn't get *dagesh* either.

<sup>* Your question would be trickier with the word בִּדְבַר discussed there, where you actually don't have a *dagesh* after a closed syllable.</sup>

Comment: Similar example: [הֲל֨וֹא כֹ֧ה דְבָרִ֛י כָּאֵ֖שׁ נְאֻם־יְהוָ֑ה וּכְפַטִּ֖ישׁ יְפֹ֥צֵֽץ סָֽלַע׃](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c1123.htm#29)